# Eclipse is executing wrong main

Tags: java

When I launch my program Eclipse just tries to launch a different program and this one does not even start.

Here's the code

```
public class multiDisplay {  
private int displayCount;
private String displayMessage;

public void  setDisplayMessage(String in)

{ displayMessage=in;

}

public  void setDisplayCount(int number)
{
 displayCount=number;
}

public void display()
{ 
    for(int i=0; i<displayCount;i++)
    {   
        System.out.println(displayMessage);
    }
}

public int getDisplayCount()
{   
    return displayCount;
}

public void display(String msg, int count)

{for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    System.out.print(msg);
    }
}
public String getDisplayMessage()
{
return displayMessage;
}
}

class multiDisplayMain {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
 multiDisplay md=new multiDisplay();

md.setDisplayMessage("Hello World!");

md.setDisplayCount(3);
md.display();                           

md.display("Goodbye cruel world!", 2);  

System.out.println("Current Message: "+ md.getDisplayMessage());
}
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  How, *exactly*, are you trying to run it?

Comment: Standard run, no custom config, eclipse mars. Top menu, run and then run again (ctrl +f11). It actually launches the previously launched program, any idea why that happens?

Comment: Are there other classes with a `main` in your project ? Check your run configuration which class you are addressing.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have been struggling with this for the past few hours, had no idea what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that your Eclipse project contains more than one class which has a `main`. Although you are seeing the code you want to execute the default run configuration calls different code. There is nothing wrong with your code.

Open `Run` / `Run Configuration` and check which are defined and which main they call:

[image: Run Configuration dialog of Eclipse]

You can even click the `Search` button which will give you an overview of classes containing a `main`.